# iOS 5.x - Segueing between view controllers

Tags: ios5, segue

Let's say we have an app which has a lot of view controllers and a navigation bar. Now, the app starts with view A, then we can press next and go to B, press next and go to C etc..
Now, in the last view, let's say Z - we have a button "go to first". What I've done is, dragged from the view Z to view A and that created a segue. I gave that segue an identifier, let's say "goToA". Now, when the button is pressed I did something like

```
-(IBAction)goToFirstPressed{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToA" sender:self];
}
```

What it does - it goes to A. But here's the important part - it doesn't go to the A that appeared on the screen for the first time, it went to another instance of view controller A. So let's say if I had in the first view controller (A) playing a video, now I go to Z then segue, I won't see that video anymore, and more important is - I can play the same video twice, overlapping the sounds.
Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue only goes in one direction. it will always make a new instance of the view you are navigating to.

You can use delegation for that.

Try [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)

You can implement that protocol method like as follows:

```
- (void) goToFirstView{

  [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 

}
```